# How to build a dashboard in Grafana that displays Jenkins jobs status?

Tags: jenkins, grafana, dashboard

want to set up a dashboard that displays jenkins job, i tried to integrate grafana with jenkins directly but it didn't work.

I tried to integrate grafana with jenkins directly but it didn't work. copied the share dashboard from grafana and added that to jenkins post build using groovy script, but nothing is displaying in the grafana dashboard.

added groovy script in post build action

```
import hudson.model.*

//get current build
def build = Thread.currentThread().executable

// grafana url for aggregate dashboard - replace time stamp with %s
        def perfResult = "https://grafana.optum.com/d/Yqv7hnOWk/jenkins-test?orgId=1&from=%s&to=%s"
// get build start and end time
        def start = build.getStartTimeInMillis();
        def end = start + build.getExecutor().getElapsedTime();

// replace time
        perfResult = String.format(perfResult, start, end);

//build the string to be added as description.
        def link = "<a href='%s'>%s</a><br/>";
        def sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(String.format(link, perfResult, "Grafana Performance Result"));

// set build description
        build.setDescription(sb.toString());
```

i expected dashboad to display the jenkins job result, but its not displaying anything.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked in a POC dashboard using Prometheus/Grafana and this is what I did:

- A python exporter, that makes calls to the API and then expose them in Prometheus format
- A prometheus server polling data from the python exporter
- A grafana server that connects to the prometheus server and display the data.

At that time (1 and 1/2 year ago) I got issues because Prometheus keep showing me last data 5 minutes, so If I erased a build from 3 days ago, it would not be displayed. I could not investigate this further due to the fact it was a simple POC very restricted in time.

Comment: i was looking for something more in details about the configuration. thanks anyways

Comment: The problem with Grafana is that it only displays data from a source. I just checked Grafana Datasources webpage and it cannot connect directly to Jenkins. So, you will need to store those metrics elsewhere, and then read it from grafana

Answer (score 0):

its pretty easy, install the prometheus exporter plugin in jenkins.  have prometheus running on the same host as your grafana instance.  set the data source to point to your jenkins prometheus endpoint...enjoy

Comment: At least at the time I made the test, the Prometheus plugin exports data about the server and not about the builds. That is why I took the build solution